# Generating all subsets of a set, so that their reunion equals the whole set

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp

I have a problem that I am trying to implement in C++. Given a set of numbers, I want to generate all the subsets, so that the reunion of these subsets equals the whole set.

For example, with A = {1,2,3} I want to obtain:
(1,2,3)
(1,2)(3)
(1,3)(2)
(1)(2,3)
(1)(2)(3) 
The order in which I obtain these subsets does not matter.

I am trying to do this in C++/RCpp because in R it tends to be a bottleneck of a code I have. My current idea is to have a structure
`X vector<vector<vector <int> > >` in which I add all the vectors one by one. 
Looping through the set A,

- for 1, I add {[(1)]} to X{1};
- I add the next elements this way; let's say I am at X{1} = [(1)(2)] and X{2} = [(1,2)] and the next number to added is 3. Then I make a loop through the elements of X. If I encounter an element with only one vector (like X{2}), then I return [(1,2)(3)] and [(1,2,3)]. If I encounter an element with two vectors (like X{1}), then I loop through the vectors and, for 1 I return [(1,3)(2)] and for 2 I return [(1),(2,3)], and finally I add [(1)(2),(3)].

The problem is that this implementation proves to be slower than a similar one in pure R, which is quite slow already.

Is there a slightly efficient way of generating these subsets?
Perhaps by generating all the subsets first (which can be easily done in R) then grouping them in this order (but I have not figured out how).

edit: the C++ code (rather long)

```
std::vector<std::vector < int> > push_one(std::vector<int> x, int add) {
  std::vector< std::vector <int> > res;
  res.push_back(x);

  std::vector<int> newvec;
  newvec.push_back(add);

  res.push_back(newvec);

  return res;
}


std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <int> > > push_two(std::vector<int> x, int add) {

  std::vector<std::vector <int> > newvec;
  std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > res;
  res.push_back(push_one(x, add));

  x.push_back(add);

  newvec.push_back(x);
  res.push_back(newvec);


  return res;
}


// push_one_rest does the same as push_one, just that it takes a 'rest' argument, that adds another (vector of vectors) at the end.
std::vector<std::vector < int> > push_one_rest(std::vector<int> x, int add, std::vector<std::vector<int> > rest) {
  std::vector< std::vector <int> > res;
  res.push_back(x);

  std::vector<int> newvec;
  newvec.push_back(add);

  res.push_back(newvec);
  res.insert(res.end(), rest.begin(), rest.end());
  return res;
}

//push_two_rest does the same as push_two but it takes the rest argument adding at the end of every element.

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <int> > > push_two_rest(std::vector<int> x, int add, std::vector<std::vector<int> > rest) {

  std::vector<std::vector <int> > newvec;
  std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > res;


  //res.push_back(push_one_rest(x, add, rest));



  x.push_back(add);

  newvec.push_back(x);
  newvec.insert(newvec.end(), rest.begin(), rest.end());

  res.push_back(newvec);


  return res;
}


// additref adds a new number.

void additref(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > &x, int add) {
  int xsize = x.size();
  for(int i = 0; i<xsize; i++) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > herevec = x[i];

    if(herevec.size()==1) {
      std::vector<int> actualvec = herevec[0];
      std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <int> > > newvec = push_two(actualvec, add);
      x.insert(x.end(), newvec.begin(), newvec.end() );
    }

    if(herevec.size()>1) {

      std::vector<int> addvec;
      addvec.push_back(add);

      for(int i=0; i<herevec.size(); i++) {

        // put the rest into rest
        std::vector<int> basis = herevec[i];

        std::vector<std::vector<int> > rest = herevec;  

        rest.erase (rest.begin()+i);


        std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <int> > > newvec2 = push_two_rest(basis, add, rest);


        x.insert(x.end(),newvec2.begin(), newvec2.end() );
      }
      herevec.push_back(addvec);
      x.push_back(herevec);
    }
  }
  x.erase (x.begin(),x.begin()+xsize);

}


// The function which adds the numbers one after another.

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <int> > > divide(std::vector<int> division) {
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector <int> > > res;

  std::vector<int> x;
  x.push_back(division[0]);
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > x2;
  x2.push_back(x);

  res.push_back(x2);


  for(std::vector<int>::iterator it4 = division.begin()+1; it4<division.end(); it4++) {
    additref(res, *it4);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: are you only interested in sets of 3? or can the set be arbitrarily large? Also, you seem to disallow empty sets ...

Comment: The set can be arbitrary large (but let's say <20, because the total number of subsets will be 2^n - 1). I don't think the empty set is so important, since the condition is that the subsets have to be paired so that their reunion equals the whole set.

Comment: If your set has `n` elements, then there are `2^(n-1)-1` different ways to split it into two non-empty subsets, but each of these can be split again ... etc. So, the total number of possible ways to plit your initial set is larger than that.

Comment: yes you are right. even if I don't store all these values in a format as I thought, I would still be happy (if I can somehow list all these subset combinations)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off using a bitset. Given a set S of N elements you can map each element of S to a bit and then generate the subset by includin elemnst corresponding to a '1'.

For esample given S = {A, B, C} you get

```
000 -> {}
001 -> {C}
010 -> {B}
011 -> {B, C}
100 -> {A}
101 -> {A, C}
110 -> {A, B}
111 -> {A, B, C}
```

Comment: I thought about that. But then I don't know how to group 100 with, for example, both (010, 001) and with (011). For example when I would do this with a length-4 set, I would have
(1000) which should be paired with [(0100), (0010), (0001)] but also with [(0100), (0011)] etc.

Comment: So you want disjoint subset whose union is the original set, right? And do you want *all* of them or just some?

Comment: Precisely. All of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `listParts` function from the "partitions" package seems to work:

```
> require(partitions)

> listParts(4)
[[1]]
[1] (1,2,3,4)

[[2]]
[1] (1,2,4)(3)

[[3]]
[1] (1,2,3)(4)

[[4]]
[1] (1,3,4)(2)

[[5]]
[1] (2,3,4)(1)

[[6]]
[1] (1,4)(2,3)

[[7]]
[1] (1,2)(3,4)

[[8]]
[1] (1,3)(2,4)

[[9]]
[1] (1,4)(2)(3)

[[10]]
[1] (1,2)(3)(4)

[[11]]
[1] (1,3)(2)(4)

[[12]]
[1] (2,4)(1)(3)

[[13]]
[1] (2,3)(1)(4)

[[14]]
[1] (3,4)(1)(2)

[[15]]
[1] (1)(2)(3)(4)

>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this function. However, seems to be extremely slow: for 1:9, for example ( called as listParts(9) ) I get with microbenchmark an average of 1.25 seconds / run, while in the R implementation of the code in my post, it takes about 84 miliseconds.